Deploy a springboot project on altervista
I'll start with make my excuse for my bad english but I'm a young student from italy and I don't know it very well.
I've created my own Springboot project using intellij IDEA and I want to deploy it on internet.
I've searched online and I've choose altervista.org as hosting service.
using altervista it say that I haven't an index page but I want from it that index the page with spring.
i've request the site and use the ftp protocol to upload my project on it (I choose the hosting with file manager) but it give me an error because it deploy my project in static mode.

Altervista is for PHP hosting not for Java. Dropping your jar over FTP won't work as they don't do hosting for Java.

What can I do for Upload my project?
Maybe there is a similar service for java or i can activate some option
